# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; on fixed div makes scroll target body occasionally

Tags: css

When I have a fixed div, in my case a mobile menu, that I added -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to (for momentum scrolling), everything seems to work absolutely fine. I can scroll my mobile menu up and down as expected. But when I just scroll up and down continuously (simply playing with the scrolling a bit), sometimes the scroll target suddenly is not the div anymore, but the body and I can't scroll the menu anymore. I then have to wait a bit, or try scrolling for a while until suddenly the mobile menu becomes the scroll target again. It's super weird. If I remove -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; the target is always the div though, so momentum scrolling somehow causes my scrolling to go through the mobile menu and target the body.